# SQL statement for a 13 character long timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a closed source application which put a 13 character long timestamp in a MySQL database. One value is for example:

```
1277953190942
```

Now I have the problem, that I have to write a sql statement which will return me all results of a table which match a special day.

So I have for example 01. July 2010 and I will get all rows where the time is in between 01. July 2010 00:00:00 until 01. July 23:59:59.

How do I have to write this sql statement?

```
select * from myTable where TIMESTAMP = ???
```

Does anyone know this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with millisecond precision, i.e. the number of milliseconds since [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch). Hence the correct statement would be

```
select * from myTable where DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) = DATE('2010-07-01');
```

Note that the query won't be fast es every value in your table will have to be converted to a date for comparison. As soon as this query starts to make problems (and not a second earlier), you may want to use an approach using 2 timestamps for the beginning and end of day which wouldn't require much conversion overhead. I'll leave this as an exercise to the eager though ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question: Is it possible that I can create a sql statement in which I have several dates? For example I need the rows for date1 = '2010-07-01', date2 = '2010-07-02', date3 = '2010-07-03', ... Of course I can do x times the sql statement, but perhaps I can do one statement for all different dates?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do something like `where DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) IN (DATE('2010-07-01'), DATE('2010-07-05'), DATE('2010-07-08'))`. This should work. Same for the BETWEEN operator (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/comparison-operators.html). I'm short on time, so I can't validate my claim right now. It should be pretty trivial though. Cheers

Comment: No, that is not what I want. If I do a "in (Date(...), ...)" I get one(!) result row. But I want to have one result row per Date.

Comment: well, you should get every matching row once, as in every SQL query. But I'm still not sure I understand your requirement. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: With this statement I get always one row (because I have a more complex statement with sum(), etc.):
select * from myTable where DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) = DATE('2010-07-01');
But I have to get one row per date. So I have the dates 2010-07-01, 2010-07-02, 2010-07-03 and for every date I need one result row and not one row for all dates together like it is done wit the IN () list.

Comment: I created a new post, because it is another topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245532/mysql-list-of-sum-for-several-conditions-in-one-sql-statement

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
 WHERE DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp /1000 ) ) between '2010-07-01 00:00:00' and '2010-07-01 23:59:59'
```

Comment: a 13 digit timestamp contains milliseconds, otherwise it would be 40 * 1000 years from epoch, thus around 42010 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch.

This number is probably the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp contains the ms :/ if you look at the time now `127 902 676 7` and the time the you have `127 795 319 0 942` you will see that it consists bar the last 4 integers of `0942` i.e .9ms, you need to convert it to a UNIX Timestamp from epoch

Depending on if your using PHP, here is a little function for you

```
<?php
function EpochToUnix($t)
{
        return mktime(substr($t,8,2),substr($t,10,2),ubstr($t,12,2),substr($t,4,2),substr($t,6,2),substr($t,0,4));
}
?>
```

But you can see wqhat you have to do