# MySQL: list of sum for several conditions in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL statement:

```
select sum(x) as "sum", "01.06.2010" as "date" from (
   select distinct a.id as ID, a.dur as x from b_c 
      inner join c on b_c.c_id = c.id 
      inner join a on c.id = a.c_id 
      inner join a_au on a.id = a_aud.id 
      inner join d on a_au.rev = d.rev 
      where 
         b_c.b_id = 30 and 
         a_au.stat != 1 and 
         DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(rtime)) = DATE('2010-06-01')
) AS SubSelectTable;
```

This statement returns one row with the colums "sum" and "date".

Now I have not only one date ('2010-06-01'), I have many dates I have to get the sum() of it, but not in one single row. I want to have per day one result row.

So, for example, the statement above returns me

```
sum            date
-------------------
 20      01.06.2010
```

Now I have the dates 2010-06-01, 2010-06-02, 2010-06-03, ...
What I can do is to write for every date one sql statement changing the DATE. So if I have 10 dates, I will have 10 sql statements for the database.
But I did want it with one SQL statement, and the result should not be the sum of all given dates, I want to have one result row per date. So the result should like that:

```
sum            date
-------------------
 20      01.06.2010
133      02.06.2010
 19      03.06.2010
 88      04.06.2010
...             ...
```

How can I do this? Does anyone know?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the mysql GROUP BY command.  Completely untested code example:

```
select sum(x) as "sum", date as "date" from (
   select distinct a.id as ID, a.dur as x, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(rtime)) as date from b_c 
      inner join c on b_c.c_id = c.id 
      inner join a on c.id = a.c_id 
      inner join a_au on a.id = a_aud.id 
      inner join d on a_au.rev = d.rev 
      where 
         b_c.b_id = 30 and 
         a_au.stat != 1
) AS SubSelectTable
group by date;
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be okay, but how can I tell the statement, that I want to have only result rows between two given dates?
I added a "... where ... and date between '2010-07-01' and '2010-07-10'" but it does not know the date column.
How can I do this?

Comment: ah, of course I could do this:
"... where ... and DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(rtime)) between '2010-07-01' and '2010-07-10'" but I think the performance is not so good, because it has to calculate the timestamp to a date twice.

Comment: solved:
group by date having date between '2010-07-01' and '2010-07-10';