# 13 Character Timestamp

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a 13 character timestamp within my application but after searching online I am at a loss.

Are these 13 character timestamps special types of timestamps? And how can one generate them?

Here is an example timestamp: 1330650156663

Comment: Where did you come up with 13 characters?  Where did that example come from?  What time does it represent?

Comment: relevant? [SQL statement for a 13 character long timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236949/sql-statement-for-a-13-character-long-timestamp)

Comment: Please don't assume other people are familiar with the same terms as you. For example. I've never heard of "13 character" timestamp, but if you explained what you mean by that term, it's not impossible I could help.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I have no idea what term I should be using. I've not used timestamps of this length before. It appears to be milliseconds thanks to some helpful answers below.

Comment: @JamesJeffery Then you should provide a **description**. What are the characteristics of this specific kind of timestamp? Where are you reading it from (e.g. is it a database and which, is it a filesystems etc.), how do you need to process it and where are you writing it to, etc, etc...

Answer (score 4):

It's the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 (unix epoche)

```
        long timestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thirteen-character timestamps are generally UNIX timestamps with a millisecond precision.

For example, 1330650156 (without the 663 milliseconds at the end) is `02 Mar 2012 01:02:36 UTC` (see http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You need milliseconds (instead of just second)

```
 TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
 long timestamp  = (long ) t.TotalMilliseconds;
 Console.WriteLine (timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware it was in milliseconds but this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
```

You probably want something like that, though you'd have to use a string operation to get it to 13 characters if it isn't already.